# @Id doesn't create primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

In my Spring Boot database project, I wanted this 'id' field to be auto-generated, unique Primary Key, but it's not. When I check the H2 database GUI there the Primary Key is some obscure, hidden 3rd column, which doesn't even list when I query the table. I attached a screenshot of it.

Screenshot of H2 database GUI:

[image]

This is my `@Entity` class.

```java
package com.schabby.springdb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Entry implements Serializable {
    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    private String text;

    public Entry() {
    }

    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: try GenerationType.IDENTITY and keep ID annotation first and then let me know

Comment: yeahhh, it works now, thank you!

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. For code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Entity
public class Entry implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String text;

    public Entry() {
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Here `IDENTITY` indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using the database identity column.

You can refer below reference to know more about different `GenerationType`.

**Reference:** https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html